# JavaScript closure triggers all inside the loop when registering OpenLayers event even with anonymous function or bind

Tags: javascript, closures, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have following code where I'm trying to add some markers to OpenStreetMaps and onClick they would trigger their own popup. lonLats is an array that has objects with properties lon, lat and text. Code is roughly the following.

```
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
var projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // transform from WGS 1984
var mapProjection = map.getProjectionObject(); // // to Spherical Mercator Projection
var zoom=16;

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);
map.setCenter (new OpenLayers.LonLat(lonLats[0].lon, lonLats[1].lat).transform(projection, mapProjection), zoom);
lonLats.forEach(function(el){
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(el.lon, el.lat).transform(projection, mapProjection);

    var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat);
    markers.addMarker(marker);

    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("",
                       marker.lonlat,
                       new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                       el.text,
                       null, true);
    (function(p, m){
            map.addPopup(p);
            p.hide();
            map.events.register('click', m, (function(){
                this.show();
            }).bind(p, null));
    })(popup, marker);
  });

</script>
```

So basically when I click on one of the markers, all popups turn visible. It seems like the classic JavaScript closure trap, but how should I register the OpenLayers event so that it only triggers the one marker I'm clicking?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark since I have no experience with openlayers, but since the event handler receives an `event` object, maybe something like `event.object.show()` will work? (or maybe `event.element.show()`)

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the map.events.register contract, instead of registering a click handler for each marker (The handler appears to be called for each marker!) register a single handler that utilizes the event object to show the selected marker.

Comment: Try using marker.popup = popup; within the foreach to create the association, and use map.events.register('click', m, function(){
               event.object.popup.show();
            }); to trigger the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was rather simple, I just needed to register the event to the marker instead. Don't know how I got that mixed up from the examples, might've been confused as the the marker itself is given as a parameter.

```
m.events.register('click', m, (function(){
    this.show();
}).bind(p, null));
```